# Scroll buttons for one div at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many events on my page, and I have one div with some images inside (scrollbar is active), and I have one function that works with arrows (scrollbar is hidden).
What I want is: I need the slide buttons to work for every event, and to move just the event you are checking out.
I have tried some methods but I cannot get it to work

```js
var next = document.getElementById('slide');
next.onclick = function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('scrollFunction');
  sideScroll(container, 'right', 25, 100, 10);
};

var back = document.getElementById('slideBack');
back.onclick = function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('scrollFunction');
  sideScroll(container, 'left', 25, 100, 10);
};

function sideScroll(element, direction, speed, distance, step) {
  scrollAmount = 0;
  var slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (direction == 'left') {
      element.scrollLeft -= step;
    } else {
      element.scrollLeft += step;
    }
    scrollAmount += step;
    if (scrollAmount >= distance) {
      window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
    }
  }, speed);
}
```

```css
.scoll-pane {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  -ms-overflow-style: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
}

.scoll-pane::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#slideBack {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: -15px;
}

#slide {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This HTML code will be repeated for every event -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="event-date mt-4">
        <h4>October 1 (Monday)</h4>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="scoll-pane mt-4" id="scrollFunction">
        <ul class="photos">
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i id="slideBack" class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
      <i id="slide" class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="event-date mt-4">
        <h4>October 1 (Monday)</h4>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="scoll-pane mt-4" id="scrollFunction">
        <ul class="photos">
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i id="slideBack" class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
      <i id="slide" class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you repeat the html for another event, the added events won't work, the slide buttons don't work anymore

Comment: @RoryMcCrossanI have updated the snippet now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're duplicating `id` attributes when they must be unique. To fix this you need to use common classes on the repeated DOM structures. Then in your JS you need to traverse this DOM structure to find the scrollable elements related to the clicked next/previous icons.

Note the loops over the `.slide` and `.slideBack` elements in order to add the event listeners to all of them individually. Also note the use of `parentElement.querySelector()` to find the related `.scroll-pane`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.slide').forEach(function(next) {
  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = this.parentElement.querySelector('.scoll-pane');
    sideScroll(container, 'right', 25, 100, 10);
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.slideBack').forEach(function(back) {
  back.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = this.parentElement.querySelector('.scoll-pane');
    sideScroll(container, 'left', 25, 100, 10);
  });
});

function sideScroll(element, direction, speed, distance, step) {
  scrollAmount = 0;
  var slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (direction == 'left') {
      element.scrollLeft -= step;
    } else {
      element.scrollLeft += step;
    }
    scrollAmount += step;
    if (scrollAmount >= distance) {
      window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
    }
  }, speed);
}
```

```css
.scoll-pane {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  -ms-overflow-style: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
}

.scoll-pane::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.slideBack {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: -15px;
}

.slide {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This HTML code will be repeated for every event -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="event-date mt-4">
        <h4>October 1 (Monday)</h4>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="scoll-pane mt-4">
        <ul class="photos">
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i class="slideBack fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
      <i class="slide fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="event-date mt-4">
        <h4>October 1 (Monday)</h4>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="scoll-pane mt-4">
        <ul class="photos">
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://robohash.org/test">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i class="slideBack fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
      <i class="slide fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to increase in the moving position as below.

```
next.onclick = function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('scrollFunction');
  sideScroll(container, 'right', 25, 300, 10);
};

var back = document.getElementById('slideBack');
back.onclick = function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('scrollFunction');
  sideScroll(container, 'left', 25, 300, 10);
};
```